# dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error ('apache2-bin' is missing )

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dpkg

Simply trying to install php5-curl via terminal....

```
parisa@parisa-VirtualBox ~ $ sudo dpkg --configure -a
parisa@parisa-VirtualBox ~ $ sudo apt-get install php5-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 php5-curl
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 571 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/27,3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 142 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package php5-curl.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'apache2-bin' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

and get this error??

Comment: I've also tried this: sudo apt-get install apache2 --reinstall  and had the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reinstall apache2 package:

```
apt-get remove apache2 --purge
apt-get install apache2
```

The other option is to move dpkg info files to some temp location:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/apache2* /some/location/path
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 --reinstall
```

Comment: when trying   sudo apt-get remove apache2 --purge  I get the same error :(

Comment: Thanks a lot :) just for others, If you get warnings about other packages missing newlines repeat the procedure recursively